# QT Creator suddenly can't compile on MacOS Monterey

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qt-creator

I have a bizarre problem with my MacOS Monterey.

This QT project always compiled without problems. After the most recent macOS Monterey OS update (12.6.1), and Xcode update, I'm getting weird errors all over the place like this one (sorry for the image, but I can't copy/paste that message).

The file is there. Line 123 is

`#include_next <wchar.h>`

Does anyone have any idea of what's happening? It seems suddenly basic C++ includes are not working anymore.

QT Creator is also updated to the latest version, as is Xcode.

[image]

Comment: Make sure that the current kit is installed: [https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-targets.html](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-targets.html)

Comment: Hi @drescherjm I'm afraid I can't see anything wrong with my Kit: it says the default desktop qt 6.3.2 for macos is installed, I never changed it. Kit and QT Versions are also both auto-detected. Not sure how the kit is linked to the files ut's actually linking from within Xcode app...

Answer (score 0):

Solution is here, together with other tips
https://web.stanford.edu/dept/cs_edu/resources/qt/troubleshooting
Deleting the .pro.user file solved the problem. I have no idea how that file was leading to errors in the included libraries, but it solved the problem.